# Facebook comments plugin not publishing comments

Tags: facebook, url, comments, publish

I have added a comments box on my page:
http://metallica-gr.net/news/welcome/welcome.html

But when I add a comment even with Post to Facebook checked, that comment is not showing on facebook. Sometimes it worked when I unchecked and rechecked the box. Is it bug or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Your source code shows you have multiple `fb-root` div tags and no app Id.

Your code:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/el_GR/all.js#xfbml=1";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

Remove one `fb-root` div tag and then create a new fb app, get its app id and append it to the connect url, i.e. `//connect.facebook.net/el_GR/all.js#xfbml=1`

Final code should look like this:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/el_GR/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=<YOUR-APP-ID>";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

Also why not use HTML5 code for plugin?

```
<div class="fb-comments" data-href="{YOUR_SITE_URL}" data-num-posts="2" data-width="470"></div>
```

And your site is missing some of the important OG meta tags, those are `og:title`, `og:url`, `og:description`, `og:type` and `fb:app_id` (Optional for moderation of comments).

Also your image referenced by `og:image` should be at least 200px in both dimensions. Correct it and it should work.

For example:

```
<meta property="og:title" content="Metallica-gr" />
<meta property="og:type" content="website" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://metallica-gr.net/news/welcome/welcome.html" />
<meta property="og:image" content="{IMAGE_URL}" />
<meta property="og:description" content="{YOUR_SITE_DESCRIPTION}" />
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="{YOUR_APPLICATION_ID}"/>
```

Don't forget to [lint](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) the url after changes, so fb servers cache new updates.

Let me know if it worked.

Comment: What you mean with "Create a new fb app" ? There was no App ID on get code of the facebook box.

Comment: So I made a new App and pasted the ID but still it's not working.